# Android: Error in discovering bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need some help in my Android application. I am trying to create an app that discovers bluetooth devices then compare the name to a string.
but I encountered 2 problems.

1: when I exit the app (back button) it exits then show me a crash message (after few seconds) .. I think the problem is with "mReceiver" (check "2nd problem).

2:(main problem) In the code bellow, the $"mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()" part has a problem. I have thrown multiple toasts every where just to check which part doesn't work, everything before this line works fine.

I'm not sure but I think the problem with not having "final" in declaring "mReciver" in the beginning --> "private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;". However adding final causes problems.

The Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1; //It's really just a number that you provide for onActivityResult (>0)

//Temp objects for testing
private String StringMeeting = "meeting";
ProgressBar bar;

//Member fields
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //declare & start progress bar
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //------------Setup a Bluetooth (Get Adapter) ------------------
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting the Adabter is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}


    //------------Setup a Bluetooth (Enable Bluetooth) ------------------
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Bluetooth is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

    //------------Finding Devices (Discovering Devices)----------------------
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "creating the mReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //last thing works
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "accessed onReceive + will create action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Waiting to discover a device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enterd the if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting device names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "displaying the name should be done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

            }else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action) = False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }
    };
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy


} //onCreate end

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    // Unregister broadcast listeners
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
}
```

Thank You For Your Time.

Comment: You say that when you click the back button, the app crashes, but you point at the point where the broadcast receiver is created as the source of the error. The broadcast receiver is created in onCreate. When back button is clicked, onDestroy is called. So whatever is failing should be failing on onDestroy.

Comment: Another point is whether you rotate the device or not before clicking the back button. Rotating the device destroys the activity and if you don't have code to handle this, then your state disappears. You might be having null references after rotating the device.

Comment: Another thing I see is the following. You check mBluetoothAdapter is  null or not, but then you call isEnabled method outside the else. In other words, enabling bluetooth and finding devices only make sense if mBluetoothAdapter is not null. You just show a toast message, but the rest of the code still runs.

Comment: 1) I know the problem is in the OnDestroy, but I pointed at the fact that mReceiver got a problem in OnCreate AND OnDestroy.
In OnDestroy you'll find:
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

Comment: 2) I did not rotate the device, and I don't think I mentioned anything about rotation problems.

Comment: 3) True, I didn't use isEnable in the else, the toast was just for testing to make sure there was a bluetooth adapter or it was null. It proved that obviously bluetooth adapter is not null. However, this should not affect the rest of the code, whereas it still execute the rest of the code without errors, then later gets stuck. because after the "if & else" it should execute the isEnable method smoothly.

Comment: Thank You neo for your time, and appreciate you helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start an activity for result in order for the user to be prompted whether the user allows Bluetooth to be enabled or not, but you don't wait for the result and try to find devices right away.

You should implement onActivityResult call back. If the result is RESULT_OK, then you start discovering devices. Enabling bluetooth takes some time.

Comment: the problem is even if the bluetooth is already on, it doesn't continue; so the problem is not with the time that enabling bluetooth takes. In fact after the isEnable(), everything works fine except mReceiver. I even added the part that my application checks the "previously paired" devices, and it takes long time then it goes to mReceiver, and still doesnt work.

Comment: I can't copy the log, but no errors seems to be found. However, I threw some log  messages to check the code .. apparently it stops working when it reaches the onRecieve and continue to work after exiting the onReceive. as if it ignores its existence.
all the log messages before and after onReceive works, but in it doesn't.